# How to launch our app when we click a link in gmail

Tags: ios, gmail

I am sending a link after signing up to the account from which user has signed up. 
Now I want that when user click on that link from the corresponding account then he/she will move to app.

is there any way to launch our app from link clicked on gmail app?

Please help...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to do perform Universal Linking.For universal linking you need to first create a “apple-app-site-association” file, which look like this :->

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": {
       "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc": {
            "paths": [
                "/wwdc/news/",
                "/videos/wwdc/2015/*"
            ]
        }
    }
 }
}
```

The applinks tag determines which apps are associated with the website. Leave the apps value as an empty array. Inside the details tag is an array of dictionaries for linking appIDs and URL paths.
The appID consists of your team ID combined with the app’s bundle ID. 
After creating file you need to upload it on your domain like www.yourHost/apple-app-site-association.
now you need to go capabilities -> Associated Domains add here a link which you want to make universal i.e, which link you want to tappable to open your app. 
Then you need to add this method in your app delegate class.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
//code here to related universal links
/* The activity type used when continuing from a web browsing session to either a web browser or a native app. Only activities of this type can be continued from a web browser to a native app.
 */
guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
  let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
  let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
    return false
}
  //do something 
   return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the use of URL scheme, you can add it to your application in the info plist file.

And use the below delegate to catch the response

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool`

You just asked for the details so this [tutorial](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/deep-linking-using-custom-url-scheme/) will help you

Comment: That's for Swift?

Comment: Updated the answer! Now it is for swift! please check